# including login credentials with a WebRequest

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to "behind the scenes" log myself into a website, from the VB code behind my ASP.NET website. But I am dumbfounded as to how to do this.

As far as I know I should be using the `WebRequest` or `Webclient` class. That is about as much as I know. I am not sure how to use the class.

I want to click a button on my website and have its `Click` event send a username and password to another website. This other site isot affiliated with mine. I realize the concept may seem stupid, but I plan on taking this further later, but Just need to know this now.

If anyone could give me some code example with explanation or direct me to a good tutorial that would be greatly appreciated!

If it helps at all, the website I am trying to log into is www.Lockerz.com

Thanks!

Comment: is the site's login expecting Active Directory credentials using Windows login, or is it using Forms Authentication?

Comment: I believe it is Forms Authentication actually

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the client site uses basic authentication you can add credentials like this:

```
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));   
myReq.Credentials = mycache;
```

If it uses form login, you can use Fiddler to sniff the data posted on a login, and perform the same request from a HttpWebRequest object. You might want to handle cookies as well if you have to perform multiple requests with the logged in user.

Reference:

- Cookies: [Automatic Cookie Handling C#/.NET HttpWebRequest+HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571964/automatic-cookie-handling-c-net-httpwebrequesthttpwebresponse)
- Cookies and POST: [HttpWebRequest POST and Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581755/httpwebrequest-post-and-cookies)
- Download class: [Characters in string changed after downloading HTML from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700638/2700707#2700707)

Comment: Thank you very much! My program runs now. What would be a good way to check to see if it actually logged on? I tried putting incorrect networkCredentials in, but it did not produce an error.

Comment: I am also trying to log into www.lockerz.com using this If that helps you out at all.

Comment: www.lockerz.com is not using basic auth, they are using a form login, so you have to post your credentials and track cookies. Download Fiddler2 to monitor what is sent when you log onto the site.