# Accessing site from a code

Tags: c#, .net

First of all I am not doing any kind of hacking, because I am using my valid credentials to access the site. I am creating an application to access that site from my windows application.

but I am not sure how to create a request for it. here is a request header which I got from chrome deveoper tool when I access the login page of the site.

[image]

than, to login I enter my credentials and it redirect it to my home page, the request header for it is here:
[image]

Any Idea how I do this via code? I am updating this question..that I know I can do this by HttpWebRequest..but I dnt know how to set that Cookie part.

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite has the ability to record web requests to make performance/load tests from them. If you are not familiar with all these requests, you could use recordings to write code on your own then.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and POST whatever data you need to it.

Comment: That I know how to use http request but I am confuse about setting that Cookie?

Comment: See this code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581755/httpwebrequest-post-and-cookies  It's in VB but the syntax shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

What derek said plus...

Last time I did this I used the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse out the __VIEWSTATE and all the other __XXX variables which will need to be posted. One will also have to remember to POST the 
 the session cookie and any authorization cookies you get back.